# Matrix snake array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, matrix

How can i write this?!
Create a function that takes a number(it can be any number) and produces a spiral matrix (two-dimensional array) with 7 columns and 6 rows where the start is the number you passed in as an argument. See images below for the pattern. In the first example snakeArray(1) was called. The second one snakeArray(-10).
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your efforts, and where you bump into an issue.

Comment: i do not tried to do it, because i don`t understand

Comment: The path is always the same - along the first row, down the last column etc only the numbers change, and they just change by adding 1 to the previous number. You need to put the correct number into each item in the array.

Comment: There are several ways to do it. One is to create the 2D array first (maybe with all null), and then maintain a "direction" (expressed in dx, dy). Start going right until you reach the border of the 2D array or until you reach a non-null value. Then turn right (swap the dx, dy pair and negate the resulting dx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. But since the size of the array is always 6x7, you can actually create a kind of template array as an array literal, which starts with 0.

Then the rest is a piece of cake: just add the argument to all the values:

```js
function snakeArray(start) {
    return [
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,  7],
        [20, 35, 36, 37, 38, 27,  8],
        [19, 34, 41, 40, 39, 28,  9],
        [18, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 10],
        [17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11]
    ].map(row => row.map(val => val + start));
}

let result = snakeArray(-10);
for (let row of result) console.log(...row);
```

So the `[...]` array literal creates the array as if the value to start with was 0. Then we iterate over the rows of that array with `map`, and then we iterate over each value in that row with a nested `map`. Then we add the start value to that value and return that. The inner `map` builds a new row with those new values, which is returned in the callback to the *outer* `map`. And that *outer* map returns the new rows as a new matrix, where *every* value will have been increased with `start`.

Comment: Can you explan please in detail how does it work?

Comment: See addition to answer.